# Sonic weapons vs Faeries: Can we survive The Cloud of Blades & Bombs?

Tags: warfare, weapons, fantasy-races

The faeries of my world are nightmare fuel.

They 5-7 cm insects that have two legs and four upper grasping limbs.  Paired with this, they have the flight characteristics of humming birds, making them near invisible, zippy dots when they are on the fly.

If that's not bad enough, they had also industrialized; giving them the access to wonderful things like shaped explosives and guns that can take out a man (they use it like fixed artillery).

Fighting against such a force armed with shaped charges that can penetrate enough material to go through your armor, which you'll want otherwise they'll bring out the razer blades and slice you to ribbons, is bad enough.  The issue is that they had developed counter measures to the most obvious tactics.

Shotguns cover only so much area and with hundreds swarming in a coordinated manner, it will be hard to get all of them before running out of ammo.

Fire is hard to armor against due to there size, with aerogel not doing much when the napalm sticks to you.  So they either spread out in coordinated swarms that attempt to flank the human with the flamethrower and plant a charge.  Alternatively, if they are in a pre-prepared position, they could wait out the flames and emerge during a opportune time.

A similarly deal with chemical weapons with bunkers as described above, though due to the square cube law gas filters have a larger volume when compared to there relative volume and weight meaning that they are more effective relative to the faeries size.  Of course, with how active faeries are and size constraints of the filters, they can realistically operate for a short amount of time.

Time enough to compromise any NBC suit that any human may be wearing.

For now lets ignore bombs as you can't just firebomb an area without either destroying what your after or get all of the underground installations (Fae dig *deep*).

The weapon that I think is a solution for this some sort of acoustic weapon tuned to the lethal frequencies of the Fae which is much lower than humans due to their size.

Is this a good hard counter measure?

If not, why?  And is it because my assumptions are wrong or is there really a better weapon system?

**Assumptions:**

- Both humans and Fae are at equal technological level, so both sides have fire arms, directed energy weapons (sonics), metallurgy etc.
- There is no magic.

Comment: You seem to be asking for opinions and for us to brainstorm and generate ideas. All 3 are not permitted on this site.

Comment: Too much fluff and not enough solid information.  If you are saying that tiny creatures massing a few grams are able to create shaped charges that they can fly with (ie a gram or so) then this is fantasy territory, since real world physics prevents creation of a shaped charge that small.  If science doesn't apply, then any answer will be "magic" by another name.

Comment: Focus on who fairies are and what kind of weapon it is. Forego all that shotgun, napalm and gas talk, you're not here to demonstrate how powerful fairies are. Answer instead those questions : How fast exactly are armed fairies and what is their threatening range? How many are they in a standard fight? What's the weapon they use (there's no hard-counter against everything unless it's extremely unbalanced)? Where do the fights take place most of the time : urban cities, open plains...?[...]

Comment: [...] Then, what's the lethal range of your sonic weapon? Is it throwing soundwaves in a ray-like fashion (most fictions do)? Can you friendly fire other humans? How (un)wieldy is the sonic weapon : pistol-sized or heavy like a rocket launcher? Do you need to "reload" it, and if so, how often and how quick?

Comment: Sound waves of the right frequency could impair their ability to fly.

Comment: You know if you make the humans stone age and the fairies edible then this is just reverse Attack on Titan.

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle snack on titania?

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle That's how it started out.

Answer (score 5):

**Frame Challenge**

And partial answer.

So - on the questions:

Faeries usage of Firearms: No. I could do the Maths, but something something recoil impulse, something mass of the Faery something energy. In short - there is no way, even with a fixed emplacement type weapon, that something that small can fire a lethal projectile, let alone something portable. Put it this way, a .22lr round is 1 inch long, that's half the size of the Faery - for a human equivalent - that would be like me having a portable Naval Artillery shell - just no.

I'm also skeptical of something that small being able to impart enough force to puncture the skin, even if using a bladed weapon or puncture an NBC suit. If we use a Hummingbird as our analogue (simply because you measured it) a 5 gram hummingbird is able to travel at 90 kph and is about the same size as your faery. If they kamakaze'd into you - they would have a total of.... 1.9 joules of energy. Not enough to puncture the skin or an NBC suite.

Sound - I mean high decibel noises and pressure waves to something so small would be pretty damaging.

However, I would just use Bug Spray. Their small size means they have a higher surface area to mass ratio - which means that aerosol poisons would be very effective against them. But let's assume they create some form of suit that allows their wings to still work (debatable) whilst making them completely sealed...

Liquid Nitrogen Sprayer. Their small size and speed means a very high metabolism, high surface area and low mass means that the cold would be devastating to them. They don't have enough thermal energy to stay warm, so their core temp would plummet and ice formations on their wings would drastically reduce their mobility, possibly causing them to drop out of the sky.

To conclude:

Without the aid of Magic - your Faery are too small and not able to impart enough energy to be lethal to humans with bladed weapons or with projectile weapons - and whilst a pressure wave could do a number on them - Aerosol poisons and aerosol liquid nitrogen would be lethal to them but not to humans (probably not *great* for humans - but....) and are readily available, in forms that can be used, without having to invent new weaponary (e.g. sonic weapons)